# Display arrow when there is overflow:hidden

Tags: html, css

Following is my jsfiddle which works fine without overflow:hidden but I have to use this property cause if I dont use it i am not able to put `...` when there is an overflow of text above certain width. Kindly help me how Display arrow when there is overflow:hidden?

http://jsfiddle.net/rP5q3/1/

```
.arrow_box {
    position: relative;
    background: #1D2027;
    border: 4px solid #1D2027;
    width:50%;
    color:white;
    display:inline-block;
      float:left;
      margin-left:2px;
      color:#FFF;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
      white-space: nowrap;
      overflow:hidden !important;
}
.arrow_box:after, .arrow_box:before {
    left: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.arrow_box:after {
    border-color: rgba(29, 32, 39, 0);
    border-left-color: #1D2027;
    border-width: 14px;
    margin-top: -14px;
}
.arrow_box:before {
    border-color: rgba(29, 32, 39, 0);
    border-left-color: #1D2027;
    border-width: 20px;
    margin-top: -20px;
}
```

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: @Popnoodles How can I display arrow when there is overflow:hidden?

Comment: use a wrapper to display the pseudo arrow , then use a child to do the text-overflow, both together are not compatible as you noticed, else you could use gradient & padding for younger browsers only http://jsfiddle.net/rP5q3/4/

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to run what you are trying. Of course is an example, if you could explain a bit more what are you trying to do I think I will be able to make a simple code to make it work with jQuery.

```
var arrowBox = $("div").find(".arrow_box");
if (arrowBox.css({"overflow" : "hidden"}){
// jQuery code to display the arrow when "overflow:hidden;"
};
```

Here you have a demo on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrSwaggalicious/rP5q3/2/).